# Emacs "stuck" colours in shell modes

Tags: emacs, eshell

Sometimes if I'm working in either a `shell` or `eshell` buffer with `ansi-color-for-comint-mode` on, and running a program which gives colourized output and then crashes while printing coloured text, the colour gets "stuck" and all subsequent text in that buffer is in that colour.  The only way I've been able to fix it is to either turn `ansi-color-for-comint-mode`off, or kill the shell buffer.

Is there a nicer way to tell a comint-derived shell buffer to "reset" the ansi colour codes?

Answer (score 5):

It's not the prettiest solution, but this function works - it just sends the right color code to reset the colors

```
(defun unstick-ansi-color-codes ()
  (interactive)
  (end-of-buffer)
  (insert "echo -e \"\033[m\"")
  (comint-send-input nil t))
```